# Decompose 4x4 matrix to absolute transforms

Tags: c++, math

My recent understanding regarding scaling matrices is that whatever translation it contains, scaling will not affect m[12], m[13], m[14] in this case.

Given:

```
Matrix4:
float m[16];

Row-Major:
m[00], m[01], m[02], m[03]
m[04], m[05], m[06], m[07]
m[08], m[09], m[10], m[11]
m[12], m[13], m[14], m[15]

m[00], m[04], m[08] = Cross vector
m[01], m[05], m[09] = Up vector
m[02], m[06], m[10] = Normal vector
m[12], m[13], m[14] = Translation vector
```

Using C++/OpenGL. As an example, zooming camera at a point in space:

```
Vector3 target = Vector3r(1, 3, 0);

Matrix4 s(MATRIX4_IDENTITY);
s.SetScale(3,3,3); /// Arbitrary value.

Matrix4 t(MATRIX4_IDENTITY);
t.SetTranslation(target);

Matrix4 tMinus(MATRIX4_IDENTITY);
tMinus.SetTranslation(-target);

Camera *camera = GetCurrentCamera();
Matrix4 matrix = camera->GetMatrix();
matrix *= t * s * tMinus;
```

IMPORTANT: The concept here is that the end result is not to carry scaling with the camera transforms.
That said, how do we extract the absolute translation and rotation from matrix while taking into account that it has been scaled?

```
camera->SetScale(1, 1, 1);
camera->SetTranslation(?); /// vector3
camera->SetRotation(?); /// quaternion
```

Then we make a new matrix from these transforms.

Comment: I'd extract the scale factor from the matrix, invert it, apply it back to the matrix, then apply that matrix to the camera?